# Using Javascript To redirect am embedded Form when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want a javascript to  redirect the embedded form below when the submit button is clicked

The form is below

```
<div class="o-form-header"><h2 id="o-form-title">Mail List Subscription Form</h2><p id="o-form-description">Please fill in and submit the form below to subscribe to our mailing list.</p></div> <form action="http://sendfree.com/subscribe.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div class="o-form-row"><label for="FormValue_EmailAddress">Email Address</label><input type="text" name="FormValue_Fields[EmailAddress]" value="" id="FormValue_EmailAddress"/></div><div class="o-form-row"><label for="FormValue_CustomField689">Your Name</label><input type="text" name="FormValue_Fields[CustomField689]" value="" id="FormValue_CustomField689"/></div> <input type="hidden" name="ret_s" value="44" /> <input  type="submit" name="FormButton_Subscribe" value="Submit" id="FormButton_Subscribe"/><input type="hidden" name="FormValue_ListID" value="8085"/><input type="hidden" name="FormValue_Command" value="Subscriber.Add" id="FormValue_Command"/></form>
```

The javascript I use below but it not redirecting to google.com after the submit button is clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("FORMBUTTON_SUBSCRIBE").onclick=function()  
  {
    window.location.href="http://www.google.com"
  }
</script>
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("FORMBUTTON_SUBSCRIBE").onclick=function()  
{
  location.replace("http://www.google.com");"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   document.getElementById("FORMBUTTON_SUBSCRIBE").onclick=function(event)  
  {

    window.location="http://www.google.com";  
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Default action on form button click is submitting of form, so we should prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I used Eventlistener but not still redirecting, check what may be wrong as am not good in javascript

```
<script>
document.getElementById("FormButton_Subscribe").addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.location.href=" http://www.google .com";
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not an answer to your original question. You should **edit** your original question to provide the additional information, and then delete this